# How do I move Key Animations into the Action Editor?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

So I have made some animations to my character using Shape Keys, and when I go into the action editor add a new Shape Key animation, it moves my old one into this thing:

[image]

How do I move the Shape Key animations into my Action Editor animations so I can use them in Unity?